# Tutorials for making mouths

Tags: modeling, animation

I would love to make a moving mouth in Blender, can someone direct me to a good tutorial?
The mouth I would be making would be for an anthro (furry) or cat, if that makes any difference.

Comment: **Questions asking for tutorials only are considered off topic** (See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/what-is-the-proper-action-for-a-question-that-requests-links-to-tutorials). If you use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and change your question to an specific issue you are experiencing it might be easier to help you. Please include images of what you have tried and some reference of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Darrin Lile has an excellent character modelling, texturing and rigging series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT1GNMevfc https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2MGttB1E7U&t